# EntityFramework concurrecy error at first record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is object Image

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }           //primary key
public string Path { get; set; } //not null
public string Name { get; set; } //not null
public string Url { get; set; }  //allows null
public string SecureUrl { get; set; } //allows null
```

EFDbImageRepository

```
public void UploadToCloud(Image image)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(image.Id);
    if(image.Id == 0)
    {
        context.Images.Add(image);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In controller in the UploadImage action

```
 ...   
 Image image = new Image();
 image.init(path, "defaultName1", "type");
 imageRepository.UploadToCloud(image);
 ...
```

At moment SaveChanges I have en exception: `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException` in EntityFramework.dll

Also I find this message: `Entity of type Image in state Added could not be updated`

As I know concurrecy error occures when two users try to modify one data at the same time. In my MVC project user load file at the form. Form sends post request to controller, that saves image to server and to database. I run app at localhost and only I can load images. I still haven't add any records.

How to add record to database with Entity Framework?

Comment: `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is thrown if you have a `rowversion` column which is a byte array in c#. I do not see this in your model so there is something you are not showing in your code or in the database.

Comment: did you have tried somewhere in code to change the entity state? or to add/remove the same entity? or did you set AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false?

Comment: @Igor I found working example in internet, and compare T-SQL representations of tables. So I set `[Id]  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY` instead of `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)` according to example. Also I found that in my entity definition was missed one int field from table(it allows null values) I add this field, I don't know what helps, but now all fine. Thanks for your comment, maybe it will save my time(or friend's) in future :)

Comment: @BassamAlugili thanks, solved

Comment: If somebody know why my solution works, post please an answer